# getElementById not a function for displaying element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

So I have perused the similar questions in this vein but they all have syntax errors. I have checked my codes with the available answers but it doesn't seem to be a syntax error; but I keep getting the same "getElementById() is not a function" error. The following is the snippets of code in question. The alert is working so ik the function is being called appropriately on the dropdown menu element option.

```
 $('.dropdown-menu a').on("click", "#1", function(e){
        alert("hi");
        getElementById("#caseReport").style.display = 'block';
  });


   <div class= "radioform" style='display:none;' id='caseReport'>
     <h3>Please answer the following questions.</h3><br>
   <form>
  Previous Credible Reports in Humans:
  <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">Yes
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">No
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">Unsure
  </label>
</form>

</div>
```

EDIT: Including the drop down div for ref

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Evidence Type
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" id= "1">Case Report</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i din't see any `dropdown-menu` element in your code?

Comment: You're using jquery - the correct syntax for selecting by id is `$('#id') `

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ***jQuery*** then do:-

```
$("#caseReport").css({'display':'block'});
//or $("#caseReport").css('display','block');
//or $("#caseReport").show();
```

If you decided to use ***javascript*** anyhow,then do:-

```
 document.getElementById("caseReport").style.display = 'block';
```

Working example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu a#1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
    $("#caseReport").css({'display':'block'});
    //or $("#caseReport").css('display','block');
    //or $("#caseReport").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Evidence Type
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" id= "1">Case Report</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class= "radioform" style='display:none;' id='caseReport'>
  <h3>Please answer the following questions.</h3><br>
  <form>
    Previous Credible Reports in Humans:
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">No
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">Unsure
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note:-

I personally said that don't mix java-script syntax with jQuery syntax. Use either-one purely.

Please check comments carefully.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it didn't work either, and now the alert doesn't appear. How did that break the code?

Comment: Thank you, I also added the drop down menu code for referral if I made a mistake there

Comment: @kam329  i have already updated my code with your html and it's working fine. check now

Comment: @kam329  if the answer worked for you then please mark the answer as accepted for the help of future visitors.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer any `DOM` location before instructing it to get any element by its ID, you can simply use the whole document in this case:

```
document.getElementById('caseReport');
```

Please note the `#` is not required in this case

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery you might as well use

```js
$(function() {
 $('.dropdown-menu a#1').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("hi");
  $("#caseReport").css("display","block");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
 <a id="1" href="#">Click Me</a>
</div>
<div class= "radioform" style='display:none;' id='caseReport'>
 <h3>Please answer the following questions.</h3><br>
 <form>
  Previous Credible Reports in Humans:
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">Yes
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">No
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name= "optradio1">Unsure
  </label>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try using document.getElementById()?

```
 document.getElementById("caseReport").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: I did and it didn't like that either?

Answer (score 0):

> To access an HTML element, JavaScript can use the **document**.getElementById(id) method.
>
> In the HTML DOM (Document Object Model), everything is a node:
>
> - The document itself is a document node
> - All HTML elements are element nodes
> - All HTML attributes are attribute nodes
> - Text inside HTML elements are text nodes
> - Comments are comment nodes